# Trouble With Database Permissions for sp_send_mail

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, database-mail

I am trying to send database mail but I am getting `EXECUTE permission denied on the object 'sp_send_dbmail' database 'msdb', schema 'dbo'.`. I code I am running is as follows:

```
SELECT SUSER_NAME(), USER_NAME();
Create USER kyle_temp FOR LOGIN Foo
EXECUTE AS USER = 'kyle_temp';
SELECT SUSER_NAME(), USER_NAME();
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail @profile_name = 'Mail Profile',
            @recipients = 'test@test.com',
            @subject = 'Test',
              @body = 'Test'
REVERT;
DROP USER kyle_temp
```

The Foo Login shows that it is mapped to the Foo User in msdb. When I look at the foo user in msdb I see that it has "DatabaseMailUserRole" Checked and has Execute on dbo `sp_send_dbmail`.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 11):

You are running into the dreaded 'sandboxed' mode of the `EXECUTE AS` context, as described in [Extending Database Impersonation by Using EXECUTE AS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188304.aspx). In short code running under `EXECUTE AS USER ...` is trusted only inside the *database* context, not at the instance context.

There are three ways out:

- the easy way: mark the current database as [TRUSTWORTHY](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187861.aspx) `ALTER DATABASE [...] SET TRUSTWORTHY ON;`
- the correct way out: use [code signing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345102.aspx)
- the cheat: use `EXECUTE AS LOGIN`

If in your environment the `dbo` of the current database is trusted then you can go with TRUSTWORTHY. It will work, but if this property is set then any `db_owner` in the current DB can elevate himself to server admin.

If you want a 'correct' solution then:

1. move this code in an stored proc
2. sign the stored proc with a certificate
3. drop the private key (so that it can never be used again to sign anything)
4. export the public key, import it in `[msdb]`
5. create user in `[msdb]` derived from this certificate
6. grant necessary permissions (AUTHENTICATE, EXECUTE on sp_send_mail) to the certificate derived user

Trivial, heh? BTW, every time you modify the signed stored proc the signature is lost and the procedure has to be repeated. See [Call a procedure in another database from an activated procedure](http://rusanu.com/2006/03/07/call-a-procedure-in-another-database-from-an-activated-procedure/) for an example.

I totally don't recommend using `EXECUTE AS LOGIN` instead.

Comment: In the long run I am trying to have this executed as a trigger, so my EXECUTE AS is a way of testing in the short term...

Comment: The cleanest way is to have a local stored proc in your DB, and have the call to `msdb.dbo.sp_send_mail` in this local SP body. Have the trigger call this local SP. Code sign the SP.